# Statistics of an array

Tags: c, arrays, max, average, min

I need a program to evaluate Min, Max, Avg and Geometric avg of any number of integers. This is what I've come up with so far. Min and Max were working just fine until I added the Avg. Now Min and Avg is working right but Max gives wrong number (usually the second greatest number). Also geometric avg gives only 0.00000. Thanks for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  int arr[100], max, i, min, size, lok = 1;
  float arit = 0, geom = 0, sum = 0, prod = 0;
    printf("\nSay how many integers you want to input: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("\nType %d integers: ", size);

      for (i = 0; i < size; i++) //put values in arr
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
            max = arr[0];
            min = arr[0];
      for (i = 1; i < size; i++) { //calc maximum
        if (arr[i]>max) {
            max = arr[i];
            lok = i+1;
          }


        if (arr[i]<min) { //calc minimum
            min = arr[i];
            lok = i+1;
          }



      for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { //calc avg
            sum = sum + arr[i];
        }
            arit = sum/size;

      for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        prod = prod * arr[i];
      }
        geom = pow(prod, 1./size);
      }


      printf("\n%d is maximum", max);
      printf("\n%d is minimum", min);
      printf("\n%f is avg", arit);
      printf("\n%f is geometric avg", geom);




  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: it is customary to place the `\n` newline at the end of the output message, not at the beginning.

Comment: Note that `prod` will be `0` because you initialised `float prod = 0` and so `prod = prod * arr[i];` will be`0`. I suggest `float prod = 1.0f`

Comment: Also you have (mistakenly) nested loops so `i` gets overwritten. Proper indentation will reveal this.

Comment: Weather Vane, thank you sir, didn't realize that. Now only the max is not working.

Comment: See my other comment about incorrect loops `{` bracing `}`. The `min` and `max` loops iterate *once* only.

Comment: I tried various types of nesting but non seemed to work.

Comment: There doesn't need to be *any* loop nesting, you just have a closing `}` brace in the wrong place (the one below `geom = `). Note too that ypou can do all of this with a single loop, no need for one loop per statistic.

Comment: Indent your code properly. It's hard to see where the blocks ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two main problems were

- a misplaced closing `}` brace
- wrong intialisation of `prod = 0`

I have made some other changes too:

- check the validity of the inputs
- use `double` instead of `float` (unless a good reason not to).
- remove the unused `lok`
- only one loop is needed for all the statistics
- moved the position of the `\n` newlines as is customary.

This is the amended code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    int arr[100], max, i, min, size;
    double arit = 0, geom = 0, sum = 0, prod = 1;   // init prod to 1

    printf("\nSay how many integers you want to input: ");
    if(scanf("%d", &size) != 1 || size < 1 || size > 100) {
        exit(1);                                    // or other action
    }

    printf("\nType %d integers:\n", size);          // added newline
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1) {
            exit(1);                                // or other action
        }
    }

    max = arr[0];
    min = arr[0];

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {                    // just one loop
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if (arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
        sum = sum + arr[i];
        prod = prod * arr[i];
    }

    arit = sum / size;
    geom = pow(prod, 1.0 / size);

    printf("%d is maximum\n", max);                 // reposition newlines
    printf("%d is minimum\n", min);
    printf("%f is avg\n", arit);
    printf("%f is geometric avg\n", geom);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: he can do all things on 1 single loop also, but I guess that the question it's about why is not working.

Comment: @Horacio I have answered that too.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem with Min and Max, and I guess also will fix geometric mean(check it) It was a problem closing for sentences

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  int arr[100], max, i, min, size, lok = 1;
  float arit = 0, geom = 0, sum = 0, prod = 1;
  printf("\nSay how many integers you want to input: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  printf("\nType %d integers: ", size);

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) //put values in arr
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
  max = arr[0];
  min = arr[0];
  for (i = 1; i < size; i++) { //calc maximum
    if (arr[i]>max) {
      max = arr[i];
      lok = i+1;
    }

    if (arr[i]<min) { //calc minimum
      min = arr[i];
      lok = i+1;
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { //calc avg
    sum = sum + arr[i];
  }
  arit = sum/size;

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    prod = prod * arr[i];
  }
  geom = pow(prod, 1./size);

  printf("\n%d is maximum", max);
  printf("\n%d is minimum", min);
  printf("\n%f is avg", arit);
  printf("\n%f is geometric avg", geom);

  return 0;
}
```

About Geometric mean you are doing this.

```
float arit = 0, geom = 0, sum = 0, prod = 0;
```

and then

```
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    prod = prod * arr[i];
  }
```

That allways will return 0 because you initialize prod at 0